# Tratar cadenas de caracteres

Tags: c#

Al recibir una cadena de caracteres por el puerto serie, en este caso poco un ejemplo envío un comando y recibo esto.

#I228.0O230.0L000B100V26.3F50.2H50.2R0120S€„€€„À

Envío otro comando difernte y recino esto otro.
#Ç—À°

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque no lo parezca, siempre cada cadena empieza por # y termina en Retorno de Acarreo.  o en programación en C# /r.

Cada cadena es diferente tamaño y formas de leerlos, también hay que leer algunas partes en bits de cada Bytes.

¿Cuál es la mejor idea para manejar cadenas?

Saludos.

Comment: La mejor idea suena a una pregunta basada en opinones.. no?

Comment: ¿Cómo lo implementas esas opciones aunque sea usando Switch?